# android studio app stops working

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble in getting my quiz to work. Whenever it runs I get a logcat error of
**12-03 18:56:57.408 4613-4613/com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz, PID: 4613
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz/com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/blue.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f060054
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/blue.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f060054
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2479)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
       at com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz.MainActivity.newQuestion(MainActivity.java:136)
       at com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32 bits
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381) 
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:787) 
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403) 
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188) 
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85) 
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94) 
       at com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz.MainActivity.newQuestion(MainActivity.java:136) 
       at com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
12-03 18:57:41.240 4613-4613/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4613 SIG: 9
```

Dose anyone know what is causing the error (I think it is something to do with the size of the blue.png file) and how do I edit the code to prevent the error? Code attached below

Main Activity.Java

```
package com.example.ayrde.stateflagquiz;   
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;  
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b_answer1,b_answer2,b_answer3,b_answer4;
    ImageView iv_flag;
    java.util.List<StateModel> list;
    Random r;
    int turn =1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
        r = new Random();
        iv_flag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_flag);
        b_answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_answer1);
        b_answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_answer2);
        b_answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_answer3);
        b_answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_answer4);
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < new Database().answers.length; i++){
            list.add(new StateModel(new Database().answers[i], new Database().flags[i]));
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list);
        newQuestion(turn);

        b_answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (b_answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "quiz finsihed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        b_answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (b_answer2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "quiz finsihed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     if(turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        b_answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (b_answer3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "quiz finsihed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        b_answer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (b_answer4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "quiz finsihed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void newQuestion(int number){
        iv_flag.setImageResource(list.get(number - 1).getImage());
        int correct_answer = r.nextInt(4)+1;
        int firstButton = number - 1;
        int secondButton;
        int thirdButton;
        int fourthButton;

        switch (correct_answer){
            case 1:
                b_answer1.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
                do {
                    secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (secondButton == firstButton);
                do {
                    thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);
                do {
                    fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == firstButton);
                b_answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
                b_answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
                b_answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());
                break;   
            case 2:
                b_answer2.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
                do {
                    secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (secondButton == firstButton);
                do {
                    thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);
                do {
                    fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == firstButton);
                b_answer1.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
                b_answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
                b_answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());
                break;
            case 3:
                b_answer3.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
                do {
                    secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (secondButton == firstButton);
                do {
                    thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);
                do {
                    fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == firstButton);  
                b_answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
                b_answer1.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
                b_answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());
                break;   
            case 4:
                b_answer4.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
                do {
                    secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (secondButton == firstButton);
                do {
                    thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (thirdButton == firstButton || thirdButton == secondButton);
                do {
                    fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                } while (fourthButton == firstButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == thirdButton);
                b_answer2.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
                b_answer3.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
                b_answer1.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

StateModel.java

```
public class StateModel {
    String name;
    int image;

    public StateModel(String name, int image){
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getImage(){
        return image;   
    }
}
```

Database.java

```
public class Database {
    int[] flags = {
      R.drawable.blue 
    };
    String[] answers = {
      "Blue"    
    };
}
```

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/blue.png`... `IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32 bits`...

Comment: Open your png in a image editor and rescale it

Comment: Is there anyway to modifty the code to avoid having to do this?

Comment: I never said modify the code. I said modify the image file

Comment: yes i know you never said but ive modified the image file and now the app just white screens with no error.

Comment: Okay, well, it's not really clear where you're trying to load your image file

Comment: If there is no more crash, [edit] your question to rephrase the problem

Comment: no because im using the code with the origial image as that produces some form of error where as the white screen gives nothing of any use

Comment: Again, there's no crash, so keeping that in your question confuses people. Edit your post with the current issue and a [mcve] of the code, please and thank you